# In using $\int_C(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{1}{z}dz=\binom{2n}{n}2\pi i$, how does it possible to compute $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos^{2n} t dt$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

In using the result $\int_C(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{1}{z}dz=\binom{2n}{n}2\pi i$, how does it possible to compute $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos^{2n} t dt$.

A hint given by the textbook is to compute $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} 2^{2n}i\cos^{2n} t dt$.

I think $C$ is simply the circle in the positive direction, i.e. $z(t)=\cos t + i \sin t$, with $-\pi \leq t < \pi$.

Is anyone could help me at this point? What change of parameter could I use here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub $z=e^{i t}$, $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Then

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} \left (z+\frac1{z} \right )^{2 n} = i 2^{2 n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dt \, \cos^{2 n}{t} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the coefficient of $z^0$ in the expansion of $\left (z+\frac1{z} \right )^{2 n}$, or $\binom{2 n}{n}$, i.e.,

$$i 2^{2 n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dt \, \cos^{2 n}{t} = i 2 \pi \binom{2 n}{n}$$

Comment: I have not seen the residue theorem in class. Could you make another version without using this last theorem?

Comment: @RobertDavis: Just expand the binomial using the binomial theorem and then sub $z=e^{i t}$ and you will get the same result.